# How to map javascript object to mvc model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I've a js object like bellow:

```
$scope.docPropIdentityModel = {
        Owner: {OwnerID:"", OwnerName: ""},
        };
```

I want to send this object to my mvc controller through ajax call. Let say the controller is like:

```
controller(test_class model)
{
}
```

and the model is like:

```
test_class
{
  public string Owner{get;set;};
}
```

I'm getting null in my controller. How can I map the js object value to my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yur json object includes two different classes.
The top level class which holds a second object (Owner).
You should have two classes:

```
public class TestClass {
    public Owner owner;

}
public class Owner {
    public String ownerId;
    public String ownerName;
}
```

Your JSON object with proper naming conventions:

```
{
"owner":{"ownerId":"yourID", "ownerName":"yourOwnerName"}
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to map just the OwnerID to my TestClass model?

Comment: Your TestClass should be like ´public class TestClass { public String ownerId;}' your JSON object like ´{"ownerId":"yourID"}´. But then you loose information about owner name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngularJS, use [$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) or [$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post).

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ReturnType Foo(YourModelClass modelClass)
{
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$http({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',                    
  data: $scope.docPropIdentityModel                   
 })
   .success(function (data) {
        alert("OK");
   })
   .error(function (data) {
        alert("error");
   });
```